# TypeError: records.map is not a function - First React project, stuck on this error with API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've been trying to fetch data from this local gov API

https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search?offset=370&resource_id=2bbef99e-9974-49b9-a316-57402b00609c&q=Mooloolaba

I've managed to get example API data to load into my project but when I go to use this API I run into errors, I think it's because I haven't got the set.state section right I'm not sure though because I've never worked with APIs before and this one I'm using is structured differently to the example.

Also I'd like to only get the latest result, this API updates every half an hour. If what I've done wrong is black and white please point me in the right direction before fixing my problem I'd like to learn where I've gone wrong :)

```js
// Waves //

const WAPI = 'https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search?offset=370&resource_id=2bbef99e-9974-49b9-a316-57402b00609c&q=Mooloolaba';

class WApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      records: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(WAPI)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ records: data.records }));
  }

  render() {
    const { records } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {records.map(record =>
          <li>
          {record.Hsig} m
            {record.Direction} direction
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: looking at your JSON data object from the link, looks as if maybe it should be `data.result.records`?

Comment: Yes, it is `data.result.records` and it seems like it is empty :)

Comment: Thank you that fixed my error message! Now it's not displaying any of the results in the rendered list just an empty ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is (as you figured out) using the wrong property from the object. It should be `data.result.records`. Now, why the data is empty? I think you are using the wrong API endpoint. I found this one for the **hot** data: https://data.qld.gov.au/dataset/coastal-data-system-near-real-time-wave-data/resource/2bbef99e-9974-49b9-a316-57402b00609c

Here is the working code. By the way, use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated in the future.

```js
const WAPI = 'https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=2bbef99e-9974-49b9-a316-57402b00609c&q=Mooloolaba';

class WApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      records: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(WAPI)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ records: data.result.records }));
  }

  renderRecords = () => this.state.records.map(record =>
      <li key={record._id}>
        {record.Hsig} m
        {record.Direction} direction
      </li>
  );

  render() {
    const { records } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {!records.length ? <p>Loading...</p> : this.renderRecords() }
      </ul>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<WApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was offsetting in the URL because the API only shows the first 100 results, now I need to work out how to get the most recent for each Location.

Comment: You are welcome. I've changed the code slightly for a "loading" example and extracted the items rendering into a separate function. Also, I've added `key` to the map items.